# Unwind Segue with Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, segue

I'm trying to use a unwind Segue with an ImageView. In my main VC I created this function for the unwind segue:

```
@IBAction func didUnwindFromSelectIcon(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    guard let imageSelectionImage = sender.source as? SelectIconViewController else {return}
    addEatImageViewEat.image = imageSelectionImage.img
}
```

Then I use this in my second VC

```
var img: UIImage?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedImage = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! SelectIconCollectionViewCell
    img = selectedImage.selectIconImageView.image

}
```

I selected the didUnwindFromSelectIcon at the CollectionViewCell on the Storyboard. I get no error or something and I'm not sure what my mistake is. My addEatImageViewEat won't show my selected Image... Hope someone see what's my mistake - Thanks in advance

**Update**:

MainVC:

```
@IBAction func didUnwindFromSelectIcon(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    guard let imageSelectionImage = sender.source as? SelectIconViewController else {return}
    addEatImageViewEat.image = imageSelectionImage.img
}
```

SecondVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindSegue" {
        if let cell = sender as? SelectIconCollectionViewCell {
            img = cell.selectIconImageView.image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the segue happens before `func collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` is called.

Instead of using that function, use `prepare(for:sender:)` to set the image:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindSegue" {
        if let cell = sender as? SelectIconCollectionViewCell {
            img = cell.selectIconImageView.image
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to set the identifier for your segue and use that in place of `"unwindSegue"` above.  To set the segue identifier, find the unwind segue in the *Document Outline* view and select it.  Then in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, set the *Storyboard Segue Identifier* to your identifier.